# Web Service URL in SoapClient and SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL error

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

There is a web service URL which returns a country's cities details. I can access this web service URL in browser by direct Http Request using GET method
 and works fine :

*[Snip: I changed my actual domain name with `example`]*

```
http://alpha.example.com/WSV2/StaticData.php?xml=<StaticDataRequest><Header><Code>TT4533</Code><Username>skyman211</Username><Password>ammkj43</Password></Header><Body><GetStaticData>cities</GetStaticData><ExtraParams><CountryCode>67</CountryCode></ExtraParams></Body></StaticDataRequest>
```

But when I try to access above URL via SoapClient :

```
/* Line 36 */
$cities = new SoapClient("http://alpha.example.com/WSV2/StaticData.php?xml=<StaticDataRequest><Header><Code>TT4533</Code><Username>skyman211</Username><Password>ammkj43</Password></Header><Body><GetStaticData>cities</GetStaticData><ExtraParams><CountryCode>67</CountryCode></ExtraParams></Body></StaticDataRequest>");
```

Gets me following error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL:
Couldn't find <definitions> in 'http://alpha.example.com/WSV2/StaticData.php?xml=
<StaticDataRequest><Header><Code>TT4533</Code><Username>skyman211</Username>
<Password>ammkj43</Password></Header><Body><GetStaticData>cities</GetStaticData>
<ExtraParams><CountryCode>67</CountryCode></ExtraParams></Body></StaticDataRequest>'
in /srv/www/htdocs/test/inc/client.php:36 Stack trace: #0 /srv/www/htdocs/test/
inc/client.php(36): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://alpha.ex...') #1 /srv/www/
htdocs/ortmas/index.php(6): InitData->getCities(67) #2 {main} thrown in /srv/
www/htdocs/test/inc/client.php on line 36
```

Comment: Does the GET call return a valid WSDL document? The error is quite clear: `Couldn't find <definitions> in...`

Comment: Yes. Get call returns valid WSDL document.

Comment: Does it have a `<definitions>` element then?

Comment: There are some elements like `<StaticDataResponse>` and `<Cities>` and ..., But there is no element with `<definitions>` name!

Comment: Then I guess you are confusing the role and content of a WSDL file and that of an actual business WS method. The SoapClient constructor needs to receive the WSDL document of the web service. That is where it gets the information about what and how the WS works. I suggest you read more about consuming a SOAP web service, it's not the same as consuming a REST service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass the URL to the WSDL, instead of the actual call itself.

Something like that for example :

> $cities = new
>   SoapClient("http://alpha.example.com/WSV2/StaticData.wsdl");

If that url worked on your browser, you can try to do the following in PHP :

```
$url = "http://alpha.example.com/WSV2/StaticData.php?xml=<StaticDataRequest><Header><Code>TT4533</Code><Username>skyman211</Username><Password>ammkj43</Password></Header><Body><GetStaticData>cities</GetStaticData><ExtraParams><CountryCode>67</CountryCode></ExtraParams></Body></StaticDataRequest>";  

$data = file_get_contents($url);
```